# Problema al utilizar Docker con React

Tags: reactjs, docker

Estoy aprendiendo a utilizar `Docker` con una aplicación `React` y su respectivo `server`, utilizo el siguiente [articulo](https://dev.to/gaabgonca/utilizando-el-poder-de-docker-para-construir-aplicaciones-mern-usando-mern-docker-1gip) como referencia.

La parte del `server` funciona correctamente, todo perfecto. El problema viene cuando realizo la parte del frontend ya que, este compila correctamente pero cuando coloco `http://localhost:3000` el navegador no me arroja nada (me dice que localhost rechaza la conexión).

Estructura del proyecto:

[image: estructura]

`DOCKERFILE` en la carpeta `client` donde contiene los archivos de react:

```
# Dockerfile for client

# Stage 1: build react client
FROM node

#  Working directory be app
WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN yarn install

#  Copy local files to app folder
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

Luego hago lo que dice el articulo:

- Se construye el contenedor usando el comando

`docker build -t myapp-react:v1 .`

- Se corre el contenedor usando el comando

`docker run -it myapp-react:v1`

- Se verifica accediendo en el explorador a `http://localhost:3000/` pero al llegar a este punto, ocurre el problema del navegador ya antes mencionado.

Esto me arroja la consola de `docker`:

> (node:43) [DEP0148] DeprecationWarning: Use of deprecated folder mapping "./" in the "exports" field module resolution of the package at /usr/app/node_modules/postcss-safe-parser/node_modules/postcss/package.json.

> Update this package.json to use a subpath pattern like "./*".

> (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)

[image: consola docker]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que puedo ver debes mapear el puerto 3000 de tu pc local con el el 3000 del container. Para esto debes especificar **-p 3000:3000** al hacer docker run.

Quedaria así: **docker run -p 3000:3000 -it myapp-react:v1**

Ahora sí puedes hacer en tu pc local **http://localhost:3000**

Incluso pudieras tener varios container corriendo a la misma vez y mapeado por puertos diferentes. por ejemplo:

//para la app 1

**docker run -p 3001:3000 -it myapp-react:v1**

//para la app 2

**docker run -p 3002:3000 -it myapp-react:v1**

Luego en tu navegador si quieres ver la app1 seria: **http://localhost:3001** y para la app2 **http://localhost:3002**

Comment: Muchas gracias, con lo que dijiste se soluciono